How to apply global filter on multiple input using tanstack table in reactjs?
I am using the Tanstack table in my ReactJS and Typescript application and using the Shadcn UI table to implement the table. I wanted to apply the global filter in my table using the Tanstack table on search input, category, and price input prices that come in the range. Tankstack table has onGlobalFilterChange in the useRecatTable hook which accepts a globalFilter in state which in string how to apply the global filter on these three inputs. Please help me to solve these filtering options. Below is the image of my table how does my table look also I am applying the Tanstack query to fetch that data which is below in my component all things are coming but not able to apply the global filter on the search input, category, and price range input

// Data From API
{
    "products": [
        {
            "_id": "6644839cbbf10a42359f8ce8",
            "name": "Turmeric",
            "price": 40,
            "category": "Charoli",
            "stock": 200,
            "purchased": 0,
            "rating": {
                "count": 0,
                "average": 0
            },
            "createdAt": "2024-05-15T09:42:52.357Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-05-15T09:42:52.357Z",
            "image": {
                "id": "rvzxnne1uq7pj5t4vtau",
                "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dx63kqko3/image/upload/v1715765950/rvzxnne1uq7pj5t4vtau.jpg",
                "_id": "6644839cbbf10a42359f8ce9"
            },
            "revenue": 0,
            "salesPerDay": 0,
            "salesPerMonth": 0,
            "totalSales": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "6644872fbbf10a42359f8d00",
            "name": "Chili Pepper",
            "price": 60,
            "category": "Charoli",
            "stock": 400,
            "purchased": 0,
            "rating": {
                "count": 0,
                "average": 0
            },
            "createdAt": "2024-05-15T09:58:07.054Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-05-15T09:58:07.054Z",
            "image": {
                "id": "cej9rn5jwbjiehlr22lx",
                "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dx63kqko3/image/upload/v1715766433/cej9rn5jwbjiehlr22lx.jpg",
                "_id": "6644872fbbf10a42359f8d01"
            },
            "revenue": 0,
            "salesPerDay": 0,
            "salesPerMonth": 0,
            "totalSales": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "66448864bbf10a42359f8d0e",
            "name": "Cumin Powder",
            "price": 30,
            "category": "Black cardamom",
            "stock": 600,
            "purchased": 0,
            "rating": {
                "count": 0,
                "average": 0
            },
            "createdAt": "2024-05-15T10:03:16.093Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-05-15T10:03:16.093Z",
            "image": {
                "id": "tolqt5hxqfjru3efzkix",
                "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dx63kqko3/image/upload/v1715767318/tolqt5hxqfjru3efzkix.jpg",
                "_id": "66448864bbf10a42359f8d0f"
            },
            "revenue": 0,
            "salesPerDay": 0,
            "salesPerMonth": 0,
            "totalSales": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "66448953bbf10a42359f8d1a",
            "name": "Danyia Powder",
            "price": 70,
            "category": "Black cardamom",
            "stock": 900,
            "purchased": 0,
            "rating": {
                "count": 0,
                "average": 0
            },
            "createdAt": "2024-05-15T10:07:15.552Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-05-15T10:07:15.552Z",
            "image": {
                "id": "aumq2fxte1csurgca5ph",
                "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dx63kqko3/image/upload/v1715767519/aumq2fxte1csurgca5ph.jpg",
                "_id": "66448953bbf10a42359f8d1b"
            },
            "revenue": 0,
            "salesPerDay": 0,
            "salesPerMonth": 0,
            "totalSales": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "66448ab0bbf10a42359f8d2c",
            "name": "Fenugreek Powder",
            "price": 40,
            "category": "Charoli",
            "stock": 350,
            "purchased": 0,
            "rating": {
                "count": 0,
                "average": 0
            },
            "createdAt": "2024-05-15T10:13:04.275Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-05-15T10:13:04.275Z",
            "image": {
                "id": "c1fifzopkgyouzpg9fbx",
                "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dx63kqko3/image/upload/v1715767856/c1fifzopkgyouzpg9fbx.jpg",
                "_id": "66448ab0bbf10a42359f8d2d"
            },
            "revenue": 0,
            "salesPerDay": 0,
            "salesPerMonth": 0,
            "totalSales": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "66448bb7bbf10a42359f8d3b",
            "name": "Hing Powder",
            "price": 32,
            "category": "Charoli",
            "stock": 780,
            "purchased": 0,
            "rating": {
                "count": 0,
                "average": 0
            },
            "createdAt": "2024-05-15T10:17:27.493Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-05-15T10:17:27.493Z",
            "image": {
                "id": "ohvmfhm7trz0qr9yc4n9",
                "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dx63kqko3/image/upload/v1715768082/ohvmfhm7trz0qr9yc4n9.jpg",
                "_id": "66448bb7bbf10a42359f8d3c"
            },
            "revenue": 0,
            "salesPerDay": 0,
            "salesPerMonth": 0,
            "totalSales": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "66448e7876ca57ac968891e9",
            "name": "Ajwain Powder",
            "price": 30,
            "category": "Charoli",
            "stock": 250,
            "purchased": 0,
            "rating": {
                "count": 0,
                "average": 0
            },
            "createdAt": "2024-05-15T10:29:12.031Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-05-15T10:29:12.031Z",
            "image": {
                "id": "i8xqxsnkfaxvwokundxc",
                "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dx63kqko3/image/upload/v1715768862/i8xqxsnkfaxvwokundxc.jpg",
                "_id": "66448e7876ca57ac968891ea"
            },
            "revenue": 0,
            "salesPerDay": 0,
            "salesPerMonth": 0,
            "totalSales": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "66448f4576ca57ac968891f5",
            "name": "Jaiphal Powder",
            "price": 45,
            "category": "Black cardamom",
            "stock": 460,
            "purchased": 0,
            "rating": {
                "count": 0,
                "average": 0
            },
            "createdAt": "2024-05-15T10:32:37.560Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-05-15T10:32:37.560Z",
            "image": {
                "id": "jccjhpjwnoqzrbsfbfdr",
                "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dx63kqko3/image/upload/v1715769075/jccjhpjwnoqzrbsfbfdr.jpg",
                "_id": "66448f4576ca57ac968891f6"
            },
            "revenue": 0,
            "salesPerDay": 0,
            "salesPerMonth": 0,
            "totalSales": 0
        }
    ],
    "totalProducts": 8,
    "totalSales": 0
}

ProductTable.tsx
import React, { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import {
  ColumnDef,
  flexRender,
  getCoreRowModel,
  getFilteredRowModel,
  getPaginationRowModel,
  getSortedRowModel,
  useReactTable,
} from "@tanstack/react-table";
import {
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableHead,
  TableHeader,
  TableRow,
} from "@/components/ui/table";
import { Checkbox } from "@/components/ui/checkbox";
import { Ellipsis, Plus, RefreshCcw, Trash2 } from "lucide-react";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { CiExport } from "react-icons/ci";
import TableSerach from "../TableSerach";
import {
  Select,
  SelectContent,
  SelectItem,
  SelectTrigger,
  SelectValue,
} from "@/components/ui/select";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { Pagination, Rating } from "@mui/material";
import useCategories from "@/hooks/queries/useCategories";
import { Category, Product } from "@/types";
import useAdmin from "@/hooks/queries/useAdmin";
import NoDataTable from "../NoDataTable";
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import {
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownMenuContent,
  DropdownMenuItem,
  DropdownMenuSeparator,
  DropdownMenuTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/dropdown-menu";
import Image from "next/image";
import {
  useDeleteAllProducttore,
  useDeleteProducttore,
} from "@/store/modalStore";
import DeleteProduct from "./DeleteProduct";
import DeleteAllProduct from "./DeleteAllProduct";

const ProductTable = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { categories } = useCategories();
  const { productsQuery } = useAdmin();
  const deleteProduct = useDeleteProducttore();
  const deleteAllProduct = useDeleteAllProducttore();
  const [globalFilter, setGlobalFilter] = useState("");
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");
  const [action, setAction] = useState("");
  const [selectDeleteProduct, setSelectDeleteProduct] =
    useState<Product | null>(null);

  const onSerachChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleCategoryChange = (val: string) => {
    setCategory(val);
  };

  const handleActionChange = (val: string) => {
    if (val === "reset") {
      setSearchTerm("");
      setCategory("");
      setPrice("");
      setAction("");
    }
    setAction(val);
  };

  const handleDeleteProduct = (product: Product) => {
    setSelectDeleteProduct(product);
    deleteProduct.onOpen();
  };

  const columns: ColumnDef<unknown, any>[] = [
    {
      id: "select",
      header: ({ table }) => (
        <Checkbox
          checked={
            table.getIsAllPageRowsSelected() ||
            (table.getIsSomePageRowsSelected() && "indeterminate")
          }
          onCheckedChange={(value) => table.toggleAllPageRowsSelected(!!value)}
          aria-label="Select all"
        />
      ),
      cell: ({ row }) => (
        <Checkbox
          checked={row.getIsSelected()}
          onCheckedChange={(value) => row.toggleSelected(!!value)}
          aria-label="Select row"
        />
      ),
      enableSorting: false,
      enableHiding: false,
    },
    {
      accessorKey: "name",
      header: "Product",
      cell: ({ row }: { row: any }) => {
        const src = row.original.image.url;
        const name = row.original.name;
        const alt = `product-${row.original.image.id}`;

        return (
          <div className="flex gap-3 items-center">
            <Image
              src={src}
              alt={alt}
              width={70}
              height={70}
              className="rounded"
            />
            <span className="break-all font-medium">{name}</span>
          </div>
        );
      },
    },
    {
      accessorKey: "price",
      header: "Price",
      cell: ({ row }: { row: any }) => row.getValue("price"),
    },
    {
      accessorKey: "category",
      header: "Category",
      cell: ({ row }: { row: any }) => (
        <div className="bg-blue-300 text-blue-700  p-1 text-sm px-4 font-medium text-center rounded capitalize">
          {row.getValue("category")}
        </div>
      ),
      meta: {
        filterVariant: "select",
      },
    },
    {
      accessorKey: "stock",
      header: "Stock",
      cell: ({ row }: { row: any }) => row.getValue("stock"),
    },
    {
      accessorKey: "salesPerDay",
      header: "Sales/Day",
      cell: ({ row }: { row: any }) => row.getValue("salesPerDay"),
    },
    {
      accessorKey: "salesPerMonth",
      header: "Sales/Month",
      cell: ({ row }: { row: any }) => row.getValue("salesPerMonth"),
    },
    {
      accessorKey: "rating",
      header: "Rating",
      cell: ({ row }: { row: any }) => (
        <div className="flex items-center mt-2.5 mb-5">
          <Rating
            defaultValue={row.getValue("rating").count}
            precision={0.5}
            readOnly
            size="medium"
          />
          <span className="ms-3">{row.getValue("rating").average}</span>
        </div>
      ),
    },
    {
      accessorKey: "totalSales",
      header: "Sales",
      cell: ({ row }: { row: any }) => row.getValue("totalSales"),
    },
    {
      accessorKey: "revenue",
      header: "Revenue",
      cell: ({ row }: { row: any }) => row.getValue("revenue"),
    },
    {
      accessorKey: "createdAt",
      header: "Created On",
      cell: ({ row }: { row: any }) =>
        dayjs(row.getValue("createdAt")).format("DD-MM-YYYY"),
    },
    {
      accessorKey: "updatedAt",
      header: "Last Update",
      cell: ({ row }: { row: any }) =>
        dayjs(row.getValue("updatedAt")).format("DD-MM-YYYY"),
    },
    {
      accessorKey: "action",
      header: "Action",
      cell: ({ row }: { row: any }) => {
        const productId = row.original._id;
        const product = row.original;
        return (
          <>
            <DropdownMenu>
              <DropdownMenuTrigger asChild className="text-center mx-auto">
                <Ellipsis />
              </DropdownMenuTrigger>
              <DropdownMenuContent>
                <DropdownMenuItem onClick={() => {}}>Show</DropdownMenuItem>
                <DropdownMenuItem
                  onClick={() =>
                    router.push(`/admin/products/edit-product/${productId}`)
                  }
                >
                  Edit
                </DropdownMenuItem>
                <DropdownMenuSeparator />

                <DropdownMenuItem onClick={() => handleDeleteProduct(product)}>
                  Delete
                </DropdownMenuItem>
              </DropdownMenuContent>
            </DropdownMenu>
          </>
        );
      },
    },
  ];

  const table = useReactTable({
    data: productsQuery.data?.products || [],
    columns,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
    getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
    getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),
    onGlobalFilterChange: setGlobalFilter,
    state: {
      globalFilter: globalFilter,
    },
  });

  const getSelectedRows = () => {
    const selectedRows = table
      .getRowModel()
      .rows.filter((row) => row.getIsSelected());
    return selectedRows.map((row) => row.original);
  };

  const selectedRows = getSelectedRows();

  // Global Filtering Table with search, category, price
  const products = useMemo(() => {
    const products = table
      .getRowModel()
      .rows.filter((row) => row.original)
      .map((row) => row.original);
    return products;
  }, [table]);

  const parsePriceRange = (priceRange: string) => {
    if (priceRange === "All") {
      return [0, Infinity]; // Return range covering all possible prices
    }
    const [min, max] = priceRange
      .split("-")
      .map((str) => parseInt(str.replace("₹", ""), 10));
    return [min, max];
  };

  const handlePriceChange = (val: string) => {
    setGlobalFilter(val);
    const filteredProducts = products.filter((product: any) => {
      const productPrice = product.price;
      const [min, max] = parsePriceRange(val);

      return productPrice >= min && productPrice <= max;
    });

    table.setOptions((currentOptions) => ({
      ...currentOptions,
      data: filteredProducts,
    }));
    
  };

  if (!table) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="bg-white border-b border-r border-l shadow rounded-lg mt-8">
        <div className="flex flex-col flex-wrap px-4 py-3 space-y-3 lg:flex-row lg:items-center lg:justify-between lg:space-y-0 lg:space-x-4 border-b border-b-gray-300">
          <div className="flex items-center flex-1 flex-wrap gap-4">
            <h5>
              <span className="text-gray-500">All Products:</span>
              <span className="dark:text-white">
                {productsQuery.data?.totalProducts}
              </span>
            </h5>
            <h5>
              <span className="text-gray-500">Total sales:</span>
              <span className="dark:text-white">
                {productsQuery.data?.totalSales}
              </span>
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-col flex-shrink-0 space-y-3  md:flex-row md:items-center lg:justify-end md:space-y-0 md:space-x-3">
            {selectedRows.length > 0 && (
              <Button onClick={deleteAllProduct.onOpen} variant="destructive">
                <Trash2 size={20} />
              </Button>
            )}
            <Button
              onClick={() => router.push("/admin/products/add-product")}
              type="button"
            >
              <Plus className="w-4 h-4 mr-2" />
              Add new product
            </Button>
            <button
              type="button"
              className="flex items-center justify-center flex-shrink-0 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 bg-white border border-gray-400 rounded-lg focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-primary-700 focus:z-10 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:focus:ring-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-400 dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700"
            >
              <RefreshCcw className="w-4 h-4 mr-2" />
              Update stocks 1/250
            </button>
            <button
              type="button"
              className="flex items-center justify-center flex-shrink-0 px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 bg-white border border-gray-400 rounded-lg focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-primary-700 focus:z-10 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:focus:ring-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-400 dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700"
            >
              <CiExport className="w-5 h-5 mr-2 text-black" />
              Export
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col px-4 py-3 space-y-3 lg:flex-row lg:items-center lg:justify-between lg:space-y-0 lg:space-x-4 border-b border-b-gray-300">
          <div className="md:max-w-md w-full">
            <TableSerach value={searchTerm} onChange={onSerachChange} />
          </div>
          <div className="flex gap-3 sm:flex-row flex-col">
            <Select
              onValueChange={(val) => handleCategoryChange(val)}
              value={category}
            >
              <SelectTrigger className="md:w-[180px]">
                <SelectValue placeholder="Category" />
              </SelectTrigger>
              <SelectContent>
                {categories &&
                  categories.map((category: Category, index: number) => (
                    <SelectItem key={index} value={category.name}>
                      {category.name}
                    </SelectItem>
                  ))}
              </SelectContent>
            </Select>
            <Select
              onValueChange={(val) => handlePriceChange(val)}
              value={price}
            >
              <SelectTrigger className="md:w-[180px]">
                <SelectValue placeholder="Price" />
              </SelectTrigger>
              <SelectContent>
                {["All", "₹1-50", "₹50-100", "₹100-150", "₹150+"].map(
                  (price: string, index: number) => (
                    <SelectItem key={index} value={price}>
                      {price}
                    </SelectItem>
                  )
                )}
              </SelectContent>
            </Select>
            <Select
              onValueChange={(val) => handleActionChange(val)}
              value={action}
            >
              <SelectTrigger className="md:w-[180px]">
                <SelectValue placeholder="Action" />
              </SelectTrigger>
              <SelectContent>
                <SelectItem value="light">Mass Edit</SelectItem>
                <SelectItem value="Action" onClick={deleteAllProduct.onOpen}>
                  Delete All
                </SelectItem>
                <SelectItem value="reset">Reset</SelectItem>
              </SelectContent>
            </Select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="w-full relative overflow-x-auto">
          <Table className="relative min-[1700px]:w-full w-[1500px]">
            <TableHeader>
              {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
                <TableRow key={headerGroup.id}>
                  {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => {
                    return (
                      <TableHead
                        key={header.id}
                        className="whitespace-nowrap text-center"
                      >
                        {header.isPlaceholder
                          ? null
                          : flexRender(
                              header.column.columnDef.header,
                              header.getContext()
                            )}
                      </TableHead>
                    );
                  })}
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableHeader>
            <TableBody>
              {table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
                <TableRow key={row.id}>
                  {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                    <TableCell
                      key={cell.id}
                      className="whitespace-nowrap text-center"
                    >
                      {flexRender(
                        cell.column.columnDef.cell,
                        cell.getContext()
                      )}
                    </TableCell>
                  ))}
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </div>
        {table.getRowModel().rows.length === 0 && <NoDataTable />}
        <nav
          className="flex flex-col items-start justify-between p-4 space-y-3 lg:flex-row lg:items-center lg:space-y-0 bg-white shadow rounded-b-lg"
          aria-label="Table navigation"
        >
          <span className="text-sm font-normal text-gray-500">
            Showing
            <span className="font-semibold text-gray-900 mx-1">
              {table.getState().pagination.pageIndex + 1}
            </span>
            of
            <span className="font-semibold text-gray-900 mx-1">
              {table.getPageCount()}
            </span>
          </span>

          <Pagination
            count={table.getPageCount()}
            variant="outlined"
            shape="rounded"
            page={table.getState().pagination.pageIndex + 1}
            color="primary"
            onChange={(_, value: number) => {
              const page = value ? Number(value) - 1 : 0;
              table.setPageIndex(page);
            }}
          />
        </nav>
      </div>

      {deleteProduct.open && (
        <DeleteProduct product={selectDeleteProduct as Product} />
      )}
      {deleteAllProduct.open && (
        <DeleteAllProduct products={selectedRows as Product[]} />
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductTable;


It's not clear what you want to do. Did you try filtering the data before it reaches the table? Use the input change to filter the data by state.

Yes, I used the search input which was working but the useReactTable globalFilter property only take string when I  am applying multiple inputs it is not working and I tried in their onChange event handler and try to get the filtered data which was coming but not set in the table like table.setOptions((currentOptions) => ({
...currentOptions,
data: filteredProducts,
})); in handlePriceChange event handler
